# console of remote apache tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, console, remote-server

Consider you work with remote server which is Tomcat.
And when you want to change something in your application there, I mean load new versions of classes over old, you want to know whether everything has been done OK. It's all about logging by remote server. As far as I know there is a possibility to do it by console somehow. But the question is how!? Any ideas?

Comment: actually I found answer to my own question. The answer is to use Putty - something like a command prompt for linux remote server